# guildMemberRemove and guildBanAdd are working like same events discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a log system for my server. Ban/Kick log.
It is working but there is a bug that, when I kick a member, It sends 1 message; but when I ban a member it sends 2 different messages.

When I kick a member:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/uGVTERa.png]

When I ban a member:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeIa7.png]

I wrote some code:

```js
const { AuditLogEvent } = require('discord.js');

// ban detector

client.on('guildBanAdd', async (ban) => {
  const fetchedLogs = await ban.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
    limit: 1,
    type: 'MEMBER_BAN_ADD',
  });
  const banLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();

  if (!banLog) return;
  const { executor, target } = banLog;

  if (target.id === ban.user.id) {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get("954475961234116719");
    channel.send(`<@${ban.user.id}> was Banned by <@${executor.id}>`)
  } else {
    return;
  }
});
```

And another one:

```js
// kick detector

client.on('guildMemberRemove', async (member) => {

    const fetchedLogs = await member.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: 'MEMBER_KICK',
    });

  const kickLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();
  if (!kickLog) return; 
  const { executor, target } = kickLog;
  if (target.id === ban.user.id) {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get("954475961234116719");
    channel.send(`<@${member.user.id}> was kicked by <@${executor.id}>`)
  } else return;

});
```

Notes: I am using Node.js v16+ and discord.js v13

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't do that, both `MEMBER_KICK` and `MEMBER_BAN_ADD` are different. Do note that audit logs are not guaranteed to be generated immediately

If you are still using this code, then I see 1 error. You are checking `ban.user.id` in both `MEMBER_BAN_ADD` and `MEMBER_KICK` event.